# How to use GWTs JSNI with Xtend

Tags: gwt, jsni, xtend

I'm creating a GWT application and using Xtend. It seems that when Xtend compiles to Java, it removes comments, so when I try to use JSNI, it turns this:

```
def native void publish() /*-{
  // do some javascript stuff through JSNI
}-*/;
```

into this:

```
public native void publish();
```

How can I configure Xtend to preserve comments or otherwise utilize JSNI with Xtend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xtend you can't. As workaround move jsni part to java class 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430929